# Devise Backbone Heroku and require.js on Rails configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, heroku, devise, requirejs

Ok, so I know I am playing with the big boys and girls here messing with front and backend MVC (even though bbone isn't exactly MVC) for an application, but this is the first real robust application I have ever worked on, and unfortunately being in the academics realm, support isn't there, esp for more cutting edge, so I am thankful in advance.

I have some errors when trying to deploy to Heroku with a Rails (3.2.2) app, and the asset pipeline has been causing problems all the time.   Since I am using BBone for the front end, and the [single]page[app] needs to know the paths to images and sounds on load, I had to use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/patrickberkeley/3879730) to attach the image paths to the App.assets to pass to the `application.js` file for require.js to start the application being built on the front end.

The problem appears to be that Devise wants: `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` while require wants: `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true` and Heroku wants in the production.rb file to be: `config.assets.compile = true`.

The error I am getting is in the gist file `assets.js.erb` where the call is made to the DB to get all the songs in the `Song` model, second to last line

```
App = {};
App.assets = {
  // Returns an object containing all of asset pipeline's image paths.
  //
  // Sample:
  //
  // {
  //   avatars/missing_avatar.png: "/assets/avatars/missing_avatar.png"
  //   chosen-sprite.png: "/assets/chosen-sprite.png"
  //   circle_green.png: "/assets/circle_green.png"
  //   circle_orange.png: "/assets/circle_orange.png"
  //   circle_red.png: "/assets/circle_red.png"
  //   circle_yellow.png: "/assets/circle_yellow.png"
  //   document.png: "/assets/document.png"
  // }
  //

  // This hash is because Rails' Asset Pipeline bundles the routes to files
  // per user session, then hands that to the user's session browser, for security.
  // So we create in Ruby (erb = embedded ruby) a hash of the images to be accessed
  // in the JS.
  images: {
    <% AssetsUtil.images.each do |img| %>
      "<%= img %>" : "<%= asset_path(img) %>",
    <% end %>
  },

  // Return a formatted URL for an asset.
  //
  // Sample:
  //
  // "/assets/document/png."
  //
  path: function(name) {
    // If the file is in our images object, pull the path from there.
    if (this.images && this.images[name]) {
      return this.images[name];
    }

    // Otherwise, create a generic asset path.
    return '/assets/' + name;
  }
};

// Currently this is ALL the songs in the DB, not just the current_user 's songs 
App.songs = {
  songs: <%= Song.all.to_json.html_safe %>
};
```

The full trace error trying to `rake assets:precompile` as suggested todo before deploying to Heroku is:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke requirejs:precompile:external (first_time)
** Invoke requirejs:test_node (first_time)
** Execute requirejs:test_node
** Execute requirejs:precompile:external
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/rake requirejs:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke requirejs:precompile:all (first_time)
** Invoke requirejs:precompile:prepare_source (first_time)
** Invoke requirejs:setup (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Invoke requirejs:precompile:disable_js_compressor (first_time)
** Execute requirejs:precompile:disable_js_compressor
** Execute assets:environment
** Execute requirejs:setup
** Invoke requirejs:clean (first_time)
** Invoke requirejs:setup 
** Execute requirejs:clean
** Execute requirejs:precompile:prepare_source
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Song
  (in /Users/me/dev/SoundOfFractions/app/assets/javascripts/assets.js.erb)
/Users/me/dev/SoundOfFractions/app/assets/javascripts/assets.js.erb:48:in `block in singletonclass'
/Users/me/dev/SoundOfFractions/app/assets/javascripts/assets.js.erb:65530:in `instance_eval'
/Users/me/dev/SoundOfFractions/app/assets/javascripts/assets.js.erb:65530:in `singletonclass'
/Users/me/dev/SoundOfFractions/app/assets/javascripts/assets.js.erb:65528:in `__tilt_70168709646800'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/tilt-1.3.4/lib/tilt/template.rb:144:in `call'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/tilt-1.3.4/lib/tilt/template.rb:144:in `evaluate'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/tilt-1.3.4/lib/tilt/template.rb:77:in `render'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:177:in `block in evaluate'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `evaluate'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `new'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `block in build_asset'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:262:in `circular_call_protection'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:240:in `build_asset'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `new'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `build_asset'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/requirejs-rails-0.9.1/lib/tasks/requirejs-rails_tasks.rake:94:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:212:in `block in each_logical_path'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each_entry'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:198:in `block in each_file'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each_file'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:210:in `each_logical_path'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/requirejs-rails-0.9.1/lib/tasks/requirejs-rails_tasks.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `call'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `block in execute'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `each'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `execute'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `each'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => requirejs:precompile:all => requirejs:precompile:prepare_source
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362...]
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:40:in `sh'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:40:in `ruby'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/requirejs-rails-0.9.1/lib/tasks/requirejs-rails_tasks.rake:85:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `call'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `block in execute'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `each'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `execute'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `each'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile => requirejs:precompile:external
```

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'railroady'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # For linux support
  gem 'therubyracer'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

# gem "better_errors", ">= 0.2.0", :group => :development
# gem "binding_of_caller", ">= 0.6.8", :group => :development

gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails-backbone'
gem "bootstrap-sass", "~> 2.3.0.0"
gem 'requirejs-rails'
gem 'ejs'
gem 'devise'


gem "better_errors", ">= 0.2.0", :group => :development
gem "binding_of_caller", ">= 0.6.8", :group => :development
gem 'color_routes'
gem 'gon'
```

So where should I start with my configuration to finish deployment?

Potential info:
  If you watch how to make custom rake tasks from Railscasts [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks), the same error occurs when running the custom rake task, and Ryan explains that the task can't access the DB because the custom task needs an `=> :environment dependency` (~4:15 in the movie) to access the User class.   Since the precompile can't access the songs model, how could I provide the same or similar dependency to the `application.js file`?

OTHER info:

To my understanding the way the asset pipeline works is for each session, it bundles the paths (so when you type something like `<%= link_to 'Sign in', new_user_path %>`, rails defines those paths in the asset pipeline, and serves it to the user.   Since Backbone is client side rendering, it needs to know the paths to the images and sounds after the page is handed from the rails server, and the only way to do this that I found was the gist listed above, where it bundles the "assets" to the JS, a similar approach to `gem 'gon'` that provides global variables to the page.   I of course am plying in new grounds, and open to restructuring, but it works in `dev` mode, so I am trying to figure out `production` as well.

Comment: sorry this is not exactly an answer but can you point out why are you using the javascript asset helper? is there a blog/article with details about it? this stuff is totally new for me.

Comment: @nEEbz comment was considered too long, so i put it in the `OTHER info:` section above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails Environment is not available to you during heroku asset precompile. As they are made once and not refreshed again tell the next deploy.   That being said.  You should move your dynamic DB related calls to your views and render the data either via API calls or "bootstraping" the data by writing your Javascript ton a script tag in the dom in json.   I normally have window.NAME_OF_APPLICATION.collections.SONGS  so they are available to me in a global scope.

Example.

```
:javascript
  window.lineItems = {lineItems: #{ @order.line_items.order("position").to_json( :include => :department).html_safe}, order: #{@order.to_json} }
```

When Backbone comes online have it call for these items. And initialize a collection for them.

Answer (score 1):

@burningpony's accepted answer above is not entirely correct.

The Rails env **is available** during heroku asset precompile if you use the labs plugin:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile